# iSCSI LUNs on different VLANs

Tags: networking, iscsi, lun, vlan

Is there any way to share different iSCSI LUNs on one iSCSI server on specific VLANs? IE lun1 would only be accessible via devices on eth0.3 and lun2 by devices on eth0.4.

I'm using [iSCSI Enterprise Target](http://iscsitarget.sourceforge.net/) to share the LUNs, don't mind switching to something else though if it can be achieved with other software.

Comment: The software can't do per-host LUNs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried the /etc/initiators.deny and /etc/initiators.allow files?

have a read of [Preventing IET from announcing unnecessary LUNs to ESX hosts](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/iscsitarget/index.php?title=The_case_of_stale_iSCSI_LUNs)  you can use this technique to deny access to all luns & then only allow the networks on the targets you want